# Can't run any program with graphics in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

After copy-pasting several examples of Java code from the internet, I've realized that I can't run any program that uses graphics. When I debug (in Eclipse), it displays a "Launching" message at the bottom of the screen but no window shows up.

This is the lastest code I've used:

```
package components;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class FrameDemo extends JFrame {

public static void main(String[] args) {
     new FrameDemo();
}

public FrameDemo() {
    super("Class Paint");       
    JButton button = new JButton("Click for more");             
    setSize(800, 600);    
    add(button);
    setLayout(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    button.setLayout(null);
    button.setLocation(100,100);
    button.setSize(200,100);
    setVisible(true);
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    g.drawString("Hello", 200, 50);
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillRect(10, 10, 10, 10);
}

}
```

Comment: it's strange, since you can see eclipse itself :-) what JRE are you using to run this app? (from inside eclipse, preferences->installed JREs)

Comment: You sure? Works fine for me. Is it behind your Eclipse window? Does it show up in your task switcher? If so, what happens if you maximize via keystrokes?

Comment: @Leo 

I'm using jre7, Standard VM

@@Dave Newton 

Nothing shows up in task manager or task switcher.

Comment: well, let's try to find the reason... in eclipse, go to help->about eclipse->installation details->configuration->view error log, copy and paste into pastebin and add the pastebin link to your question please

Comment: It doesn't let me click on View Error, only Copy To CLipboard.

Comment: have you put your class (FrameDemo) in the component package? maybe the reason is that you get an error,so you cannot run the program at all.

Comment: Exits before Windows gets around to show you.

Comment: It is in the component package.

It might be exiting before the windows shows indeed, how can I fix it then?

Comment: @Leo http://pastebin.com/5dpN0msT Here's the link for the Eclipse Juno (reinstalled another version of Eclipse, still doesn't work).